# unit testing on dao class

Tags: java, unit-testing, dao

ok I need some help. I have this method in my DAO class and I need to test it:

```
public boolean saveOrUpdateUser(User user) {
    boolean res = false;
    try {
        this.getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(user);
        res = true;
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        res = false;
        this.logger.error("DataAccessException", e);
    }
    return res;
}
```

and below is my test method:

```
   public void saveAndUpdateUserTest() {
              User user =new User ();
              user.setUserid(12);
              user.setFirstname("John");
              user.setLastname("Smith");

              assertEquals(12,user.getUser_id());
              assertEquals("John",user.getFirstname());
              assertEquals("Smith",user.getLastname());

       }
```

I need to call this method somehow in saveAndUPdateUserTest but I don't know which parameter to pass! anyone can help?

public boolean saveOrUpdateUser(User user) {..}

User user means what?
I have a class user.java containing set and get methods.

Thanks in advance. I'm still a beginner and I need advice and help how to proceed.

Comment: If you're enough of a beginner that you're not sure how method calls work, you should spend some time learning the basics of the language before tackling something like object persistence.

Comment: You need to create an instance of the DAO class that the `saveOrUpdateUser` method exists on in your test class and then call the method, passing the example User you created in the test method.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, but the code, whatever the test you write, is wrong. Exceptions thrown by Hibernate are not recoverable, an you should thus not catch them and pretend nothing happened. The code should be

```
public void saveOrUpdateUser(User user) {
    this.getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(user);
}
```

or, if you really want logs:

```
public void saveOrUpdateUser(User user) {
    try {
        this.getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(user);
    } 
    catch (DataAccessException e) {
        this.logger.error("DataAccessException", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Another note: `HibernateTemplate` is [documented](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html) as "you should not use this class anymore". It doesn't even exist anymore for Hibernate 4.

I concur with the comment. If you don't understand objects and method arguments, learn the basics of Java first. Spring and Hibernate are many levels above the basics, and you'll hit walls if you don't understand basic Java/programming concepts.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void saveAndUpdateUserTest() {

              //here is your variable of type User
              User user =new User ();
              user.setUserid(12);
              user.setFirstname("John");
              user.setLastname("Smith");

              assertEquals(12,user.getUser_id());
              assertEquals("John",user.getFirstname());
              assertEquals("Smith",user.getLastname());

              //you need to pass a variable with type User
              saveOrUpdateUser(user);

       }
```

[this](http://www.wikihow.com/Call-a-Method-in-Java) will be a good point to start.

Comment: saveOrUpdateUser(user) this variable am not understanding. what do i need to pass?

I have an interface UserDao, then a class UserDaoImpl which implements the interface.(this class contains saveAndUpdateUser(User user) .

Comment: @user2703420: read this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html.

Comment: when i insert this line :
 //you need to pass a variable with type User
              saveOrUpdateUser(user);



it tells me this method is undefined. the variable 'user' is taking all the 3 values that is id,first name and last name?? am i right or wrong?

Comment: if you have method saveOrUpdateUser in your DAO class, then you should instantiate your DAO class and then call saveOrUpdateUser on it.

Comment: thanks.
I have another method call:
public User retrieveUserById(int id) {...}

how to i call this method in my test method?i've already instantiate the class. this method is of type User. how do i proceed? am stuck here..

Comment: From where do you want to call this method? And where does this method resides? Maybe you should provide more details about your classes and their methods.

Comment: I have a class : public class UserDaoTest {..} where i am doing all the test for UserDaoImpl. i've already done for the method saveOrUpdateUser(). Now i want to do for this method: public User retrieveUserById(int id) {...}  ..the type is User thats why am stuck!

Comment: it's return type of the method. I really recommend you to learn some basics of Java language.

Comment: yes i know it's the return type. but how i call the method in my test clasS?

Answer (score 0):

You should never catch exceptions the way you are doing that in your code. Back to your question, remember the primary TDD pattern called AAA - arrange, act, assert.

Arrange is the place you initialize your SUT (system under test)
Act is there the action happens (call the test system)
Assert is there you check the results.

```
public void anyKindOfTest() {
   // arrange

   // act

   // assert
}
```

In your case,

```
public void shouldStoreUser () {
  // arrange
  User user = new User ("John", "Smith");
  UserStorage userStorage = new UserStorage();

  // act
  userStorage.store(user);

  // assert
  assertNotNull(user.id);  
}
```